# Consulta em uma tabela do SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Olá, pessoal. Preciso fazer uma consulta no SQL SERVER mas o mesmo está me retornando valores incorretos.
Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exercício proposto eu devo retornar as seguintes informações:

- Extraia a menor, maior, média e a soma das vendas de cada mês do ano
  de 2000, em ordem ascendente.
- Retorne a mesma consulta anterior, mas    somente os registros que
  tiverem média de vendas superior a 500.

Como consigo extrair as vendas de cada mês do ano?
Abaixo vou postar o código SQL que foi usado pra criação do banco:

```
CREATE DATABASE CONCESSIONARIA
GO
USE CONCESSIONARIA
GO

CREATE TABLE TB_ANO
(
        ID_ANO              SMALLINT    IDENTITY        -- 32.767
    ,   ANO                 SMALLINT

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_ANO_ID_ANO            PRIMARY KEY (ID_ANO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_ANO_ID_ANO            CHECK (ID_ANO <= 200)
)

INSERT TB_ANO
( ANO )
VALUES
( 2000 ),
( 2001 ),
( 2002 ),
( 2003 ),
( 2004 ),
( 2005 )

CREATE TABLE TB_MES
(
        ID_MES              SMALLINT    IDENTITY ( 15 , 3 )  -- E O FATO DE NÃO PODER ULTRAPASSAR 200 REGISTROS
    ,   MES                 SMALLINT

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_MES_ID_MES            PRIMARY KEY (ID_MES)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_MES_ID_MES            CHECK (ID_MES <= 612) 
)

INSERT TB_MES
( MES )
VALUES
( 01 ),
( 02 ),
( 03 ),
( 04 ),
( 05 ),
( 06 )

CREATE TABLE TB_MODELO
(
        ID_MODELO       SMALLINT    IDENTITY
    ,   DESCRICAO       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_MODELO_ID_MODELO      PRIMARY KEY (ID_MODELO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_MODELO_ID_MODELO      CHECK (ID_MODELO <= 200)
)

INSERT TB_MODELO
( DESCRICAO )
VALUES
( 'GOL 1.6 MSI' ),
( 'PALIO FIRE 1.0 ' ),
( 'KA 1.6 MPI' ),
( 'RENEGADE STD 1.6' ),
( 'COROLLA ALTIS' ),
( 'CG 125 STD' )

CREATE TABLE TB_FABRICANTE
(
        ID_FABRICANTE   SMALLINT        IDENTITY
    ,   NOME            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,   CIDADE          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,   ENDERECO        VARCHAR(100)    
    ,   UF              CHAR(02)        
    ,   TELEFONE        VARCHAR(20)
    ,   CONTATO         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_FABRICANTE_ID_FABRICANTE      PRIMARY KEY (ID_FABRICANTE)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_FABRICANTE_ID_FABRICANTE      CHECK (ID_FABRICANTE <= 200)
)

INSERT TB_FABRICANTE
( NOME , CIDADE , ENDERECO , UF , TELEFONE , CONTATO )
VALUES
( 'VOLKSWAGEN' , 'SÃO BERNARDO' , 'RODOVIA ANCHIETA S/N' , 'SP' , '2000-9999' , 'VOLWSWAGEN@VOLWSWAGEN.COM' ),
( 'FIAT' , 'BETIM' , 'AV. ENG. LUIS CARLOS' , 'MG' , '04571-010' , 'FIAT@FIAT.COM' ),
( 'FORD' , 'SÃO BERNARDO' , 'AV. TABOÃO' , 'SP' , '2000-9999' , 'FORD@FORD.COM' ),
( 'JEEP' , 'SÃO BERNARDO' , 'AV. SABURÔ' , 'SP' , '09751-510' , 'JEEP@JEEP.COM' ),
( 'TOYOTA' , 'SOROCABA' , 'ROD. CASTELO BRANCO' , 'SP' , '7770-652' , 'TOYOTA@TOTOTA.COM' ),
( 'HONDA MOTORS' , 'MANAUS' , 'AV. ANHAGUERA' , 'MA' , '2000-555' , 'HONDA@HONDA.COM' )

CREATE TABLE TB_VEICULO
(
        ID_VEICULO              SMALLINT                IDENTITY
    ,   DESCRICAO               VARCHAR(50)             NOT NULL
    ,   VALOR                   DECIMAL ( 8 , 2 )       NOT NULL -- CHEGARÁ A CASA DOS R$ 200.000,00. COM ESSA DEFINIÇÃO DE CAMPO: R$ 999.999,99
    ,   ID_MODELO               SMALLINT            
    ,   ID_FABRICANTE           SMALLINT
    ,   ID_ANO_FABRICACAO       SMALLINT
    ,   DATA_COMPRA             DATE                    NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_VEICULO_ID_VEICULO            PRIMARY KEY (ID_VEICULO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_VEICULO_ID_VEICULO            CHECK (ID_VEICULO <= 10000)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VEICULO_ID_MODELO             FOREIGN KEY (ID_MODELO)             REFERENCES  TB_MODELO(ID_MODELO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VEICULO_ID_FABRICANTE         FOREIGN KEY (ID_FABRICANTE)         REFERENCES  TB_FABRICANTE(ID_FABRICANTE)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VEICULO_ID_ANO_FABRICACAO     FOREIGN KEY (ID_ANO_FABRICACAO)     REFERENCES  TB_ANO(ID_ANO)
)

INSERT TB_VEICULO
( DESCRICAO , VALOR , ID_MODELO , ID_FABRICANTE , ID_ANO_FABRICACAO , DATA_COMPRA )
VALUES
( 'GOL'         ,       250000.99 ,     1 , 1 , 1 , '2020-09-15' ),
( 'PALIO'           ,   130000.99 ,     2 , 2 , 2 , '2020-09-05' ),
( 'KA'          ,       40000.50 ,      3 , 3 , 3 , '2005-01-01' ),
( 'RENEGADE'    ,       250000.99 ,     4 , 4 , 4 , '2020-09-15' ),
( 'COROLLA'     ,       102110.99 ,     5 , 5 , 5 , '2020-09-15' ),
( 'CG 125 STD'  ,       222222.99 ,     6,  6 , 6 , '2020-09-15' )

CREATE TABLE TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS
(
        ID_VENDAS           SMALLINT        IDENTITY
    ,   QTD                 SMALLINT        NOT NULL
    ,   ID_VEICULO          SMALLINT
    ,   ID_ANO_DA_VENDA     SMALLINT
    ,   ID_MES_DA_VENDA     SMALLINT

        CONSTRAINT  PK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_ID_VENDAS           PRIMARY KEY(ID_VENDAS)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_ID_VENDAS           CHECK(ID_VENDAS <= 10000)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_QTD_MIN             CHECK(QTD >= 1)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  CK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_QTD_MAX             CHECK(QTD <= 5000)

    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_ID_VEICULO          FOREIGN KEY(ID_VEICULO)         REFERENCES  TB_VEICULO(ID_VEICULO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_ID_ANO_DA_VENDA     FOREIGN KEY(ID_ANO_DA_VENDA)    REFERENCES  TB_ANO(ID_ANO)
    ,   CONSTRAINT  FK_TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS_ID_MES_DA_VENDA     FOREIGN KEY(ID_MES_DA_VENDA)    REFERENCES  TB_MES(ID_MES)
)

INSERT TB_VENDAS_ANUAIS
( QTD , ID_VEICULO , ID_ANO_DA_VENDA , ID_MES_DA_VENDA )
VALUES
( 2222 , 6 , 2 , 21 ),
( 1111 , 6 , 2 , 21 ),
( 1000 , 1 , 1 , 15 ),
( 2000 , 2 , 3 , 18 )
```

Comment: Tudo indica o uso de valores incorretos da chave artificial na inclusão dos registros da tabela TB_VEICULO.

Comment: Foi o uso de valores incorretos das chaves, arrumei elas e consegui retornar os valores corretamente. Agora como consigo extrair as vendas de cada mês do ano?

Comment: Estude a cláusula GROUP BY, juntamente com a função de agregação adequada, bem como a cláusula HAVING.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado. No primeiro consegui fazer sem utilizar o HAVING, porém no segundo utilizei ele. Obrigado pelas dicas.